# Time change as per the TimeZone

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I do have a dropdown that has multiple Country listed in that when I select a particular Country,The time on each page of the application where ever I am displaying it must be changed as per the selected Country Timezone.  e.g If from the dropdown I have selected the US then on entire application The time should be displayed as per US timeZone.

Comment: So? share what you have tried so far...
There are plenty of ways to do this. Session variables. Config settings. Pushing the value in the layout and displaying it where ever applicable.

Comment: I havent started yet..Went through several posts..one standard way that i ma finding is to store the time in UTC and subtracting from the offset..but how to do this..that I need to know as it is as per the dropdown change..

Answer (score 1):

1. You can show the timeZone by the inbulit function of `TimeZoneInfo`

   ```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Value,
                    new SelectList(TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().ToList(),
                                            "id", "DisplayName", Model.Value))
   ```

2.You can convert any timezone to UTC using the following function:

```
 ConvertToUTC(DateTime datetime){
     //Get the Time zone from the time zone id.
       TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(Model.Value);
     //Convert time from utc to the local time zone.
       time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(datetime, zone);
   }
```

3. In layout/Views you can display this time by pushing it in a `ViewBag`